# siunitx and \meter

Tags: errors, siunitx

I've found (here in french https://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/%C3%89crire_de_la_physique#Extension_siunitx) that I could use the package `siunitx` to write the unit but it doesn't work :

A minimal code to test :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}


\title{Test}
\author{Cécile Moulin}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

text text text
\metre

\end{document}
```

The error :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 81 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator-language-
mappings.tex))) (./test.aux)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translator-bas
ic-dictionary/translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg)
(./test.toc)
! Undefined control sequence.
\metre ->\ERROR 

l.18 \metre
```

I've tried with/without  `\( \)` and with `\meter` too, it's the same

Comment: In order not to disturb the rest of the document the unit macros can only be used in the second argument to `\SI{}{}` or in the argument to `\si{}`. The first is used to typeset value+unit and the later is used to typeset just a unit. So use `\si{\metre}` instead of `\metre`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally these units only work within `\si{...}` (and similar commands), but if you want to use them in normal text, you can use the `free-standing-units=true` of the `siunitx` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[free-standing-units=true]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\si{\metre} % for the unit alone

\SI{42}{\metre} % for value and unit

\metre % this needs free-standing-units=true

\SI{10}{\nano\meter}

\SI{10}{\nm}

\SI{10}{nm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where can I find documentation about \SI{}{} ? I didn't find... So, the first part is for the value. What about nano and cie ? 
I have a unit which is '10 nm', so I think that the 10 is in the second part but is it true ?

Comment: @Ccile You can find the documentation of siunitx at http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/siunitx/siunitx.pdf -- for the 10 nm, please see my updated answer, `\nano` is prefix to meter. Why would 10 be the second part?

Comment: Ok, thanks.
For 10 nm, you think it's better so or I can't do another way ?

Comment: @Ccile Sorry, I don't understand your last comment, can you rephrase the question?

Comment: You can define custom units, so you could set it up to allow `\SI{633}{\nm}` if you wanted.  I tend to do this only for more complicated units, like `\per\centi\metre` (to stick with a spectroscopy theme)

Comment: 10 nm is the unit. "x is in 10nm" and you used 10 as a value but for me it's a part of the unit. and I would use `\si{10\nano\meter}`

And I try to do something for 10^-21 (instead of the 10) but I don't find, could you help me ?
Ok, I succeed : `\si{10^{-21}}\liter}` I don't know why it doesn't work before...

Comment: @Ccile The unit and the number should be separate `\SI{10}{\nm}` or `\SI{10}{\nano\metre}`. For exponents, do you mean `\SI{10e-21}{\metre}` perhaps?

Comment: @Ccile I guess I would simply write `x is in \SI{10}{\nano\meter}`, but maybe I misunderstood your question. Maybe it would be best to ask a question and include how the output should look like?

Comment: @Ccile Just saw the edit you made to your comment. I would write `\SI{e-21}{\liter}`

Comment: @JosephWright You're the author don't you ? (sorry if it's not the place)
When 10 is a "value" I understand but here it's part of the unit. So if the size is 4u it's 4 10nm (yes it's 40 nm but for me there is a difference)

Comment: @samcarter I've no idea on how the output should look like. 
How would you write "4 u" when u is 10 nm (or 10nm ?)